# glBufferSubData , Haven't implemented type-inference for lists yet - instanced rendering

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, glut, opengl-3

Porting over a chapter 7 example of instanced rendering from Superbible OpenGL 7th ed. and run into a problem with the function **`glBufferSubData`**

Whatever I do to it, it won't accept the data.  Make it into a pointer, a byte string, list itself.  Please help any assistance would be very much appreciated.  Thank You.

Update: Using the excellent answer from Rabbid76 the function **`glBufferSubData`** is now accepting the data and the numpy version is very nice, the ctypes version is an insightful answer and very good to know. Also, about the 2nd parameter, it does indeed need to be a int or long, not a `GLuint(0)` in python.

Update and Success: Another very fine answer by Rabbid76 to get the rendering working.
The function **`glVertexAttribPointer`** needs a pointer to the lengths of the initial lists of data so it can offset.  Thank You very much.

source code to: instancedattribs.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import time
import ctypes

fullscreen = True

try:
    from OpenGL.GLUT import *
    from OpenGL.GL import *
    from OpenGL.GLU import *
    from OpenGL.raw.GL.ARB.vertex_array_object import glGenVertexArrays, glBindVertexArray
except:
    print ('''
    ERROR: PyOpenGL not installed properly.
        ''')
    sys.exit()


import numpy as np


square_buffer = GLuint(0)
square_vao = GLuint(0)
square_program = GLuint(0)



square_vs_source = '''
#version 410 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 instance_color;
layout (location = 2) in vec4 instance_position;

out Fragment
{
    vec4 color;
} fragment;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = (position + instance_position) * vec4(0.25, 0.25, 1.0, 1.0);
    fragment.color = instance_color;
}
'''

square_fs_source = '''
#version 410 core
precision highp float;

in Fragment
{
    vec4 color;
} fragment;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    color = fragment.color;
}
'''



class Scene:

    def __init__(self, width, height):

        global square_buffer
        global square_vao
        global square_program

        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        square_vertices = np.array([
            -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
             1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0], dtype='float32')

        instance_colors = np.array([
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], dtype='float32')

        instance_positions = np.array([
            -2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             2.0, -2.0, 0.0, 0.0,
             2.0,  2.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            -2.0,  2.0, 0.0, 0.0], dtype='float32')

        glGenVertexArrays(1, square_vao)
        glGenBuffers(1, square_buffer)
        glBindVertexArray(square_vao)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, square_buffer)

        offset = 0  # not GLuint(0)

        bufferSize = (len(square_vertices) + len(instance_colors) + len(instance_positions))*4
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferSize, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(square_vertices)*4, square_vertices)
        offset += len(square_vertices)*4

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(instance_colors)*4, instance_colors)
        offset += len(instance_colors)*4

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(instance_positions)*4, instance_positions)
        offset += len(instance_positions)*4

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
        offsetInstanceColor =  len(square_vertices)*4
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(offsetInstanceColor))
        offsetInstancPosition =  (len(instance_colors) + len(instance_positions))*4
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(offsetInstancPosition))


        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2)

        glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 1)
        glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1)

        square_program = glCreateProgram()

        square_vs = GLuint(0)

        square_vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(square_vs, square_vs_source)
        glCompileShader(square_vs)
        glAttachShader(square_program, square_vs)

        square_fs = GLuint(0)

        square_fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(square_fs, square_fs_source)
        glCompileShader(square_fs)
        glAttachShader(square_program, square_fs)

        glLinkProgram(square_program)
        glDeleteShader(square_vs)
        glDeleteShader(square_fs)


    def display(self):

        black = [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ]
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black)

        glUseProgram(square_program)
        glBindVertexArray(square_vao)
        glDrawArraysInstanced(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4, 4)

        glutSwapBuffers()

    def reshape(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def keyboard(self, key, x, y ):
        global fullscreen

        print ('key:' , key)
        if key == b'\x1b': # ESC
            sys.exit()

        elif key == b'f' or key == b'F': #fullscreen toggle

            if (fullscreen == True):
                glutReshapeWindow(512, 512)
                glutPositionWindow(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))
                fullscreen = False
            else:
                glutFullScreen()
                fullscreen = True

        print('done')

    def init(self):
        pass

    def timer(self, blah):

        glutPostRedisplay()
        glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), self.timer, 0)
        time.sleep(1/60.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    glutInit()


    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)

    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512)

    w1 = glutCreateWindow('OpenGL SuperBible - Instanced Attributes')
    glutInitWindowPosition(int((1360/2)-(512/2)), int((768/2)-(512/2)))

    fullscreen = False
    many_cubes = False
    #glutFullScreen()

    scene = Scene(512,512)
    glutReshapeFunc(scene.reshape)
    glutDisplayFunc(scene.display)
    glutKeyboardFunc(scene.keyboard)

    glutIdleFunc(scene.display)
    #glutTimerFunc( int(1/60), scene.timer, 0)

    scene.init()

    glutMainLoop()
```

expected rendering output:
[image: picture of output of rendering]

Ported from: [instancedattribs.cpp](https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb7code/blob/master/src/instancedattribs/instancedattribs.cpp)

Comment: To create a gl context version > 2.1 (you use 4.1) with `glut` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48472427/3871028)

Comment: @Ripi2 I think you've put the comment to the wrong question. The question is about how to set the parameters to `glBufferSubData` in python by using PyOpenGL. You'r comment isn't even related to this. The example works fine, apart of the call to `glBufferSubData`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 May be you're right. But we often see users giving a wrong clue to his issue, don't we?

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes you're right, but not in this case. I'm close to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In compare to [`glBufferData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferData.html), [PyOpenGl](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)'s [`glBufferSubData`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBufferSubData.html) the `size` parameter can't be omitted.
You've to pass the size of the buffer (in bytes) and a pointer to the buffer. But note, the 2nd and the 3rd parameter have to be a python `int` or `long`, even PyOpneGL's `GLuint` will cause an error.

You've some possibilities, either create an array PyOpenGL's `GLfloat`

```py
offset = 0
dataArray = (GLfloat*len(square_vertices))(*square_vertices)
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(dataArray)*4, dataArray)
```

or use pythons built-in [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library:

```py
import ctypes
```

```py
offset = 0
dataArray = (ctypes.c_float*len(square_vertices))(*square_vertices)
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(dataArray)*4, dataArray)
```

or create a [NumPy](https://www.numpy.org/) array:

```py
import numpy as np
```

```py
offset = 0
dataArray = np.array(square_vertices, dtype='float32')
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(dataArray)*4, dataArray)
```

Note, for the 2nd and 3d parameter you can use a cast to either `int` (e.g `int(offset)`) or `long` (e.g. `long(offset)`).

---

Further note, the offset and size parameters to `glBufferData`, `glBufferSubData` and `glVertexAttribPointer` are values in size of bytes rather than the number of elements of the arrays.
The size in bytes is calculated by the number of elements multiplied by the size of 1 element.
The size of 1 element is 4, since the size of `float` (`GLfloat`, `ctypes.c_float`, `'float32'`) in bytes is 4.

If a named buffer object is bound, then the last parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store, but the type of the parameter is still a pointer.
So you've to use `ctypes.c_void_p(offset)`. If offset is 0 it is possible to pass `None`.

```py
bufferSize = (len(square_vertices) + len(instance_colors) + len(instance_positions))*4
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferSize, None, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(square_vertices)*4, square_vertices)
offset += len(square_vertices)*4

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(instance_colors)*4, instance_colors)
offset += len(instance_colors)*4

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, len(instance_positions)*4, instance_positions)
offset += len(instance_positions)*4

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, None)
offsetInstanceColor =  len(square_vertices)*4
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(offsetInstanceColor))
offsetInstancPosition =  (len(instance_colors) + len(instance_positions))*4
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(offsetInstancPosition))
```

---

[image]

Comment: May I ask, what is the *4 mean?  Is it the size of each data element in the numpy array due its type being float32?

Comment: @StanS. The size in bytes is the number of elements multiplied by the size of 1 element.  The size of a `float` is 4 bytes.