# Point Cloud Distortion when Drawing with modern OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, pyopengl

I found this [nice tutorial](https://nrotella.github.io/journal/first-steps-python-qt-opengl.html) of drawing and rotating a cube with PyQt and modern OpenGL. My objective was to adapt the script for point clouds, by doing the following (see also code below):

1. Load point cloud using Open3D and extract coordinates & colors as numpy arrays
2. Create Vertex Buffer Objects (VBOs) from the arrays
3. Change the drawing function to `gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_POINTS, ...)`

Unfortunately then the point cloud is very distorted and thin (see screenshot). It should actually be a room with chairs and walls.

**Do you see if I made a mistake with the VBOs or drawing? Or is there a better way of loading a point cloud?**

[image: Example of distorted point cloud with modern approach]

I tested the example with the old fixed pipeline (`glBegin(GL_POINTS)` ... `glEnd()`) and there the point cloud is correctly drawn (but also the performance really bad!).

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore      # core Qt functionality
from PyQt5 import QtGui       # extends QtCore with GUI functionality
from PyQt5 import QtOpenGL    # provides QGLWidget, a special OpenGL QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import OpenGL.GL as gl        # python wrapping of OpenGL
from OpenGL import GLU        # OpenGL Utility Library, extends OpenGL functionality
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import sys

# Loading the point cloud from file
def load_pointcloud():
    pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("../pointclouds/0004.ply")
    print(pcd)
    print("Pointcloud Center: " + str(pcd.get_center()))
    points = np.asarray(pcd.points)
    colors = np.asarray(pcd.colors)

    return points, colors

#### here was only the GUI code (slider, ...) , which works fine! ####
        
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.qglClearColor(QtGui.QColor(250, 250, 250))     # initialize the screen to blue
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)                   # enable depth testing

        self.initGeometryPC()

        self.rotX = 0.0
        self.rotY = 0.0
        self.rotZ = 0.0

    def setRotX(self, val):
        self.rotX = val

    def setRotY(self, val):
        self.rotY = val

    def setRotZ(self, val):
        self.rotZ = val
        
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        aspect = width / float(height)

        #GLU.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)   #GLU.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)
        gl.glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 100.0)
 
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        
    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        gl.glPushMatrix()                       # push the current matrix to the current stack

        gl.glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -5.0)          # third, translate cube to specified depth
        #gl.glScale(.5, .5, .5)                 # second, scale point cloud
        gl.glRotate(self.rotX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotate(self.rotY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotate(self.rotZ, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gl.glTranslate(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)        # first, translate point cloud center to origin

        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertVBO)
        gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colorVBO)

        gl.glPointSize(2)
        gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_POINTS, len(self.pointsIdxArray), gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.pointsIdxArray)
        
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        gl.glPopMatrix()    # restore the previous modelview matrix
        
    # Push geometric data to GPU
    def initGeometryPC(self):
        points, colors = load_pointcloud()
    
        self.pointsVtxArray = points
        self.vertVBO = vbo.VBO(np.reshape(self.pointsVtxArray, (1, -1)).astype(np.float32))
        self.vertVBO.bind()
        
        self.pointsClrArray = colors
        self.colorVBO = vbo.VBO(np.reshape(self.pointsClrArray, (1, -1)).astype(np.float32))
        self.colorVBO.bind()
        
        self.pointsIdxArray = np.arange(len(points))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: your VBO usage is totally unclear, but since `colorVBO` seems to be the last one that got bound, you will most likely source your position data from the color VBO. Your usage of the `gl*Pointer()` functions is wrong, the last argument ia a byte offset into the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` object, but you seem to specify the buffer names instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @derhass! You were right, it takes the color as position. When I comment all the color VBO code, it shows the correct point cloud in white. Although I am a bit confused. It only works, when I keep the `gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertVBO)`. If I change the last parameter to 0 as it expects a pointer to the first vertex coordinate, it does not work anymore. So is it maybe about the stride parameter (, but the VBO should be tightly packed)? I did not find an example with these commands, could you hint me to the correct configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search I came upon this [stackoverflow-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56794726/10334964). I adapted my code to that answer by storing point coordinates and colors together in one vbo-object (`gl.glGenBuffers(1)`). Then I define the vertex and color pointer with the specific stride and offset:

- `gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 6*4, None)`

  - *Stride= 24 bytes: [x, y, z, r, g, b] * sizeof(float)*
- `gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, 6*4, ctypes.c_void_p(3*4))`

  - *Offset= 12 bytes: the rgb color starts after the 3 coordinates x, y, z*

And finally I use `gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_POINTS, 0, noOfVertices)` for drawing the point cloud.

The full code can be seen below (marked with `### NEW ###` comments):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore      # core Qt functionality
from PyQt5 import QtGui       # extends QtCore with GUI functionality
from PyQt5 import QtOpenGL    # provides QGLWidget, a special OpenGL QWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import OpenGL.GL as gl        # python wrapping of OpenGL
from OpenGL import GLU        # OpenGL Utility Library, extends OpenGL functionality
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import ctypes 
import sys                    # we'll need this later to run our Qt application

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)    # call the init for the parent class

        self.resize(300, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hello OpenGL App')
        
        self.glWidget = GLWidget(self)
        self.initGUI()
        
        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.setInterval(20)   # period, in milliseconds
        timer.timeout.connect(self.glWidget.updateGL)
        timer.start()
        
    def initGUI(self):
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        gui_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(gui_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        gui_layout.addWidget(self.glWidget)

        sliderX = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sliderX.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.glWidget.setRotX(val))

        sliderY = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sliderY.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.glWidget.setRotY(val))

        sliderZ = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        sliderZ.valueChanged.connect(lambda val: self.glWidget.setRotZ(val))

        gui_layout.addWidget(sliderX)
        gui_layout.addWidget(sliderY)
        gui_layout.addWidget(sliderZ)
        
class GLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        QtOpenGL.QGLWidget.__init__(self, parent)

    def initializeGL(self):
        self.qglClearColor(QtGui.QColor(100, 100, 100))     # initialize the screen to blue
        gl.glEnable(gl.GL_DEPTH_TEST)                       # enable depth testing

        self.initGeometry()

        self.rotX = 0.0
        self.rotY = 0.0
        self.rotZ = 0.0

    def setRotX(self, val):
        self.rotX = val

    def setRotY(self, val):
        self.rotY = val

    def setRotZ(self, val):
        self.rotZ = val
        
    def resizeGL(self, width, height):
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_PROJECTION)
        gl.glLoadIdentity()
        aspect = width / float(height)

        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0, aspect, 1.0, 100.0)
        gl.glMatrixMode(gl.GL_MODELVIEW)
        
    def paintGL(self):
        gl.glClear(gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        gl.glPushMatrix()    # push the current matrix to the current stack

        gl.glTranslate(0.0, 0.0, -3.0)    # third, translate cube to specified depth
        #gl.glScale(20.0, 20.0, 20.0)       # second, scale cube
        gl.glRotate(self.rotX, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotate(self.rotY, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gl.glRotate(self.rotZ, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        gl.glTranslate(-0.5, -0.5, -0.5)   # first, translate cube center to origin

        # Point size
        gl.glPointSize(3)
        
        ### NEW ###
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo)

        stride = 6*4 # (24 bates) : [x, y, z, r, g, b] * sizeof(float)

        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, stride, None)

        gl.glEnableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        offset = 3*4 # (12 bytes) : the rgb color starts after the 3 coordinates x, y, z 
        gl.glColorPointer(3, gl.GL_FLOAT, stride, ctypes.c_void_p(offset))
        
        noOfVertices = self.noPoints
        gl.glDrawArrays(gl.GL_POINTS, 0, noOfVertices)

        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        gl.glDisableClientState(gl.GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        ### NEW ###

        gl.glPopMatrix()    # restore the previous modelview matrix
        

    def initGeometry(self):
    
        vArray = self.LoadVertices()
        self.noPoints  = len(vArray) // 6
        print("No. of Points: %s" % self.noPoints)
        
        self.vbo = self.CreateBuffer(vArray)

        
    ### NEW ###

    def LoadVertices(self):
        
        pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("../pointclouds/0004.ply")
        print(pcd)
        print("Pointcloud Center: " + str(pcd.get_center()))
    
        points = np.asarray(pcd.points).astype('float32')
        colors = np.asarray(pcd.colors).astype('float32')
        
        attributes = np.concatenate((points, colors),axis=1)
        print("Attributes shape: " + str(attributes.shape))
        
        return attributes.flatten()

    def CreateBuffer(self, attributes):
        bufferdata = (ctypes.c_float*len(attributes))(*attributes) # float buffer
        buffersize = len(attributes)*4                             # buffer size in bytes 

        vbo = gl.glGenBuffers(1)
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
        gl.glBufferData(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffersize, bufferdata, gl.GL_STATIC_DRAW) 
        gl.glBindBuffer(gl.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
        return vbo
        
    ### NEW ###


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, I still did not find the correct parameters for initial approach above with two separate VBOs for coordinate and color. So I am happy for further comments.